# Distribution of values as a graph in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a set of 1-D data (0,0,0,1,2,1,1,5,6,1,1,100,1,etc) and I'd like to generate a graph from it that shows the number of values in a set of ranges. I.e
0 - 3
1-7  - 8
8-30 - 0
30+ - 1

The data set grows daily so I'd like process to be a simple and automated as possible.

(As I'm sure to be asked for more details - The values are the number of days between a ticket being issued and it being closed. I'd like to get feel for how long the tickets are open for.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). In Excel 2003 and later, it's an [available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214269) [feature](http://www.math.kent.edu/~honli/teaching/statistics/Chapter2/Excell_Histogram.html) in the Analysis ToolPak.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an extra couple of columns to the end of the list of numbers, along these lines:

```
Column B: =if(AND(A1>=0,A1<=3),1,0)
Column C: =if(AND(A1>=1,A1<=7),1,0)
Column D: ...
```

...And then drag it down and have a sum somewhere (`=SUM(B:B)`, `=SUM(C:C)`, ...) that you graph.  Of course, that's probably a little more manual than you're after...

Comment: I must admit I was hoping for a magic button to do it all for me, but as the data needs a little tweeting a little more will not hurt. Thanks.